# How setConcurrency method works in Spring JMS

Tags: spring-jms

I am using ActiveMQ with Spring Boot. I have read about the `setConcurrency` method of Spring JMS. As per my understanding if we set 2 (this is the max limit) then two concurrent consumers will be created for a listener (assuming I have only one listener/consumer) on load basic on queue. Now I want to understand how it divide the load and on which basic. On how many messages on the queue will it create the 2 consumers?

Also in case of queue will one message delivered to exactly one consumer?

And do we need to ensure the thread safety in our code while setting the concurrency?

Comment: Just to clarify, the `setConcurrency` method is *not* part of JMS. It is part of the Spring JMS framework.

Comment: Ya Mr Justin ,Sorry i took it in JMS in  generic term. Can you please give some inputs on my questions on concurrency. It would be a great help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question(s).  If you set the concurrency to 2, then you will have 2 JMS listeners (each on a different thread) on the single JMS connection/session that is managed by the Spring listener container.

These two listeners will look like any other 2 message consumers to your JMS message broker.  Messages will be delivered to only one listener/consumer.  In general, you should not need to worry about thread safety with multiple listeners.  Obviously, it is certainly possible to write non-thread safe message handling application code (2 threads updating some application level data structures at the same time), but the Spring JMS code is thread-safe.

Comment: Addition to this. I have one issue which is related to setting DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory . I have define the bean for this but the moment i create this bean. My Listener start giving exception MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to NotificationModel.when i comment the bean, then it works fine. I have created jmsTemplate and jacksonJmsMessageConverter bean also. I am not able to identify the root cause of this. 
I debug and found that below line returning class java.lang.String in PayloadMethodArgumentResolver
Class<?> payloadClass = payload.getClass();